# ExpandableListAdapter cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

i have done this on my other android app and it worked flawlessly but when i do this in another app it doesnt work.

i keep getting an error saying "ExpandableListAdapter cannot be resolved to a type"

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdListener,
        OnClickListener {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdap;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Full Screen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the list view
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        prepareListData();
        listAdap = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter, show the list
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdap);

        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

                    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent,
                            View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                            long id) {
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExpandableListAdapter` is an interface, it cannot be instantiated. You should use `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` or `extends` `BaseExpandableListAdapter` and override its methods if you want more flexibility.

Comment: like i said, i did it just like this before in my other android app and it worked fine, i just cant see why it isnt working now. i did everything exactly the same.

Comment: is `ExpandableListAdapter` included somewhere in your project?

Comment: what do you mean included?, as in imported or a class made called ExpandableListAdapter?

Comment: `ExpandableListAdapter(Context, List<>,HashMap<>)` is not a constructor that is part of any `Class` that is part of Android. It is a custom `Class`. So if you didn't code it, someone else has. The point being that you need to add it to your project structure.

Comment: yes i have that included in my code i just didnt upload it here because since the error didnt mention anything about it i didnt think it would matter. But yes i have those in my code

Comment: did you check your imports?

Comment: yes i checked my imports...everything is good the only thing i DONT have imported is the ExpandableListAdapter. Why? because i didnt need to import it before it worked well and it still is working well without importing it in my other app. and even when i do import it here in my new app i still get an error saying cannot instattiate this type

Comment: That is what I mean. It is telling you you cannot instantiate Android's `ExpandableListAdapter`. Whomever created this custom `ExpandableListAdapter` should have used another name for it. Remove the import that says `android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter` and make sure you import the one you have included to your project. You probably had your adapter as an inner class before that is why the import wasn't needed

Comment: you were absolutely right, there were so many classes in the other app that i missed that one, thank you so much for your help

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Please mark this question as answered.

Comment: It is part of the same answer. No need to add another answer.